# SOLVED: Remote mercurial server fails in changegroup.notify with an exception

Tags: mercurial, wsgi, notify

Pushing changes to a remote mercurial repo is reporting an error in my changegroup.notify hook.  It worked with an old 2.7 release of mercurial, but is broken now.

My server has

```
Python 3.9, hg --version is 
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 6.3.1)
```

The relevant repo's hgrc has

```
changegroup.notify = python:hgext.notify.hook
```

The hook reports an exception:

```
>: hg --traceback push
pushing to https://[redacted]
searching for changes
remote: adding changesets
remote: adding manifests
remote: adding file changes
remote: added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files
remote: error: changegroup.notify hook raised an exception: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
remote: (run with --traceback for stack trace)
```

Why the exception, when I am using what is supposed to just work
out of the box?

**Update:** Re-ran the test pushing from an account on the same machine as the server (thanks @LazyBadger), got the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/mercurial/hook.py", line 116, in pythonhook
    r = obj(ui=ui, repo=repo, hooktype=htype, **pycompat.strkwargs(args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/hgext/notify.py", line 589, in hook
    n = notifier(ui, repo, hooktype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/hgext/notify.py", line 326, in __init__
    self.stripcount = int(self.ui.config(b'notify', b'strip'))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

**Solution:**
Turns out this is the error you get if you haven't updated your hgrc in years.  Used to be that adding the hook to your [.]hgrc was all that was required.  Now you have to enable notify as well, so, e.g.

```
[extensions]
notify=

[hooks]
changegroup.notify = python:hgext.notify.hook
```

You also need some things to allow the email notication to work, for example if you have personal email support on the same server:

```
[reposubs]
* = [my email on the server]

[email]
from = Mercurial Notification <noreply@mydomain>

[smtp]
host = localhost
```

Comment: 1. It's old hook, created in 2.x Python, while now you have 3.9 2. Re-read "**remote: error:** changegroup.notify hook raised an exception" - if you want stacktrace, you must to run ``pull --traceback` **on server** in order to see local output